# Add jquery ui css

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

I want to use the jquery ui, but I'm missing the css in below environment:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  }
});

$( "body" ).append('<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"><p>test</p></div>');
```

Believe I'm missing this part:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

How can I use the style from the jquery ui framework? Link: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Comment: why are you doing it like that? you can just simply add the stylesheet from the head section. Your confused is very confusing

Comment: haha well I can't in this case

Comment: inserting the content through a third party tool that's only based on javascript/jquery

Comment: then you should've stated the reason, so you can get specific answer

Comment: sorry! sorry! sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the `css` file to the `head` tag using `appendTo()`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $("<link/>", {
      rel: "stylesheet",
      type: "text/css",
      href: "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    }).appendTo("head");
  }
});

$("body").append('<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"><p>test</p></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">` into your  `<head>` tag in your `HTML` file.

Check the documentation: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In between your `<head> </head>` tags define the below code and you can use all the functionalities of Jquery UI.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

An ajax call is made when you want asynchronous communication between your backend and front end. Please remove the ajax call and continue developing your code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).